# Best way to get acclimated with a new Ruby on Rails project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What tools or steps would you recommend to someone who is brand new to a project and they are trying to get acclimated to a Ruby on Rails codebase that has no testing?

I am considering something like: https://codeclimate.com/ to help run some analysis on the code but I wanted other suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the command line tool `wc` to find where the code hotspots are.  Running `wc ./app/models/**/*.rb | sort -nr` on my Mac gives me a pretty good idea of where the code is sitting.  You can replace models with controllers or any other directory to find the details there.

Once I have a good idea of where things are, it's easier to find the larger and more complex areas of code.  A brief description of the project and a run of wc should give you a pretty good idea of which data models and controllers are the most complex, and give you an idea of where to go for further investigation.

If the project is well tested I would definitely take the time to read through the spec headings.  I'd take time to read through the implementation details of specs that interest me.

The Ruby Rogues podcast has a pretty good episode about code reading that you may find helpful: http://rubyrogues.com/031-rr-code-reading/

Answer (score 0):

I'm hoping this is a will tested project... If it is,  I always read through the tests first as they give you an understanding of what the expectations of each piece of code is.  This its by far the best method that has worked for me.